# Error installing homestead on windows 10

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm having problems trying to install Homestead on windows 10.

I just made fresh Virtualbox and Vagrant (1.9.1) installations. Then, when running

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

I got the following error:

```
The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
Error: Failed writing body (0 != 7445)
```

After searching for solutions, people were solving the problem by installing the MS Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributables, which I did, but still have the same error.

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: This looks identical to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/error-running-vagrant-box-add-laravelhomestead-on-windows-10)